# Determine protocol used to load javascript

Tags: javascript, https

I have javascript file, located on one domain, e.g:
http://mydomain.com/script.js

Some pages (from other domains) include my javascript using SCRIPT tag. They can include it via http or https

```
<script src="http://mydomain.com/script.js"></script>
or
<script src="https://mydomain.com/script.js"></script>
```

Also they can include my script using 3rdparty iframes, e.g:

```
<iframe src="http://3rdparty.com/frame.php">
```

where http://3rdparty.com/frame.php outputs

```
<script src="http://mydomain.com/script.js"></script>
or
<script src="https://mydomain.com/script.js"></script>
```

I can edit only static javascript file script.js on mydomain.com.

How I can detect what protocol used to load my javascript (https://mydomain.com/script.js or http://mydomain.com/script.js)?

Comment: From where? I.e. where do you want to perform the check?

Comment: From http://mydomain.com/script.js script. I have access only to http://mydomain.com/script.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that you have any ability to identify within the code how it has been loaded. The best suggestion I can come up with is to have the http and https point to different locations ( i.e. be different sites ) and have something within the code that indicates which one is being picked up.

> var protocol='http'

or

> var protocol='https'

It does mean maintaining two files, and two sites though.

ETA: I thought James Wiseman had the answer, but of course that will only return the protocol of the PAGE, not the SCRIPT. If you know these are related, that would work ( often the https is loaded on https pages and vv ). But it is not definitive.

It is a good solution if you can be confident that the protocol on hte page is the same as on the script.

Answer (score 19):

You can use a [protocol relative URL:](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2010/02/10/using-protocol-relative-urls-to-switch-between-http-and-https/)

```
<script src="//mydomain.com/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: I do not need include my file. My file included by other sites, I just need to know what protocol they used to include my file

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
document.location.protocol + "//mydomain.com/script.js"
```