# Wordpress : To load all asset files coming from HTTP to HTTPS?

Tags: wordpress, https, external, blocked

I'm using `Wordpress HTTPS` plugin to force `Admin` mode to run under `HTTPS`.
Its fine for Admin Panel.

But still, once i'm under `HTTPS` mode, every front pages are broken because of, it is saying some front-pages `Asset Files` **are coming as normal `HTTP`** (without 'S') which are then getting blocked to load onto page.

Than resulted in rendering the page looking messy.

So to be more clear again,

- When i call the site in `HTTPS / SSL` mode .. some asset files, like:

  - `http://www.my-another-site.com/something.js`
  - `http://www.my-another-site.com/something.css`
  - `http://www.my-another-site.com/something.jpg`
  - ... etc

.. are BROKEN. ***(Because i'm in `https` mode and those above files are coming as `http`)***

So how to make Wordpress to FORCE LOAD those whatever files?
*(I DON'T CARE WHETHER IT IS SECURE OR NOT. Just want the site under `https://...` to be rendering properly.)*

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a protocol relative URL (dropping both the `http` and `https` from the URLs) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531707/determine-protocol-used-to-load-javascript/6531760#6531760).

According to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82940/how-can-i-enqueue-protocol-relative-external-ajax-googleapis-com-scripts) you'll need to be on a recent version of WordPress (I'd assume 3.5) for it to work with `wp_enqueue_script`.

Comment: But how to use it? I used: `add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "test"); function test() { wp_enqueue_script('test123', '//www.mysite.com/test123.css);}` .. but not coming up?

Comment: Could be a few things.  First, you're missing a closing quote after `test123.css` (it should be `'//www.mysite.com/test123.css'`).  But more likely, you should be using [wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) for stylesheets.